# Как расставить знаки "+" и "-" между цифрами числа так,чтобы результат вычислений был равен заданому значению?

Tags: python, алгоритм, перебор

*Наткнулся я на такую задачку* : **"Расставить знаки + и - между цифрами числа так чтобы результат был равен X. Вывести лексикографически наименьшую такую расстановку".**

Вот сразу мне в голову прибегнуло решение с помощю полного перебора (**brute force**),так как длина числа равна 20.

Но я не понимаю как организовать цикл чтобы перебрать все такие расстановки,а потом останется только сравнить их с **X**.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать,или дать источник определенной информации(так как задача "*типовая*").

Примерчик :)

```
4
11211
```

Все возможные ответы:

```
1+1+2+1-1
1+1+2-1+1
1-1+2+1+1
```

Лексикографически наименьший:

```
1+1+2+1-1   <-- ето ответ :)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо перебрать все четырех-разрядные двоичные числа. Каждое такое число соответствует одному варианту расстановки минусов (цифра `0`) и плюсов (цифра `1`).

Например:

```
1-1-2-1-1 - число 0000
1-1-2-1+1 - число 0001
1-1-2+1-1 - число 0010
1-1-2+1+1 - число 0011
и так далее ...
1+1+2+1+1 - число 1111
```

Вариантов, как Вы уже догадались, `2^4 = 16`.

Comment: Все элегантно и понятно,спасибо)